# changing page style sheet in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i tried to make an extension that change the page style sheet. i change some style like background color but i can't change the whole style sheet

**manifest.json** file

```
{
  "name": "change stylesheet",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "Set this page's style",
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

part where java script call in popup.htm

```
function click() {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
      {code:"document.getElementById('stylesheet').href = 'style1.css'"});
  window.close();
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Is there a `id="stylesheet"` element?

Answer (score 8):

Susantha - you just need to include your css file in your manifest:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

```
{
"name": "My extension",
 ...
  "content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
  "css": ["mystyles.css"],
  "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
}
 ],
  ...
 }
```

You will need to override existing styles with `!important` and follow the precedents for styles as you normally would have to. If there is an inline style then you might need to rewrite it with js code.